# Running job in endless loop

Tags: sql-server

I have some C# CLR to parse a directory looking for files on the filesystem.  I want this to run in an endless loop (preferably managed via SQL jobs).  Hoping someone can suggest the best and most efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Ben.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a .net FileSystemWatcher process and keep this processing out of sql server? see details of a folder watcher here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory

Comment: In your agent job ... `while 1=1 begin .. your code -- end waitfor delay '00:00:01'`

Comment: Be **very** careful with waitfor.. "Each WAITFOR statement has a thread associated with it. If many WAITFOR statements are specified on the same server, many threads can be tied up waiting for these statements to run. SQL Server monitors the number of threads associated with WAITFOR statements, and randomly selects some of these threads to exit if the server starts to experience thread starvation."

Comment: Thanks guys.  I wanted to keep as much as possible in database (rather than controlling processes via OS) as we may not have access to the operating system in production.  Instead of using WAITFOR in job execution, would I be better off building the delay into CLR code (although suspect the threading discussion will be the same...)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:
- You have the looping and sleep code in the CLR code
- You know how to call said code from SQL agent (a stored procedure wrapper if nothing else)
- Your process is ok with the occasional sub-minute downtime 
- Your process will not lose any data if it fails part way through (i.e. the next run will process the data the failed run was trying to process)

then I would propose a SQL agent job that is sceduled for every minute, and the job step itself have say, 10 retries set (advanced page) so that it will usually restart itself immediately if it fails.
Why just 10? Because if it starts consistently failing, you will want to get notification quickly (via agent job failure notification settings). That will be an email a minute.
Of course, if it fails 10 times sporadically, you'll get a false alarm notification, but you can quickly see from the job history whether it's failing consistently or just sporadically.